# Mock MikroORM class in jest to unit test methods decorated with @UseRequestContext

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, nestjs, mikro-orm

I'm writing unit tests for my provider class, which is ran and used in a queue, hence I needed to decorate some methods with `@UseRequestContext` decorator (according to documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/mikroorm#request-scoped-handlers-in-queues).

The problem shows up when it comes to unit test the provider methods.
I have created a following testing module:

```
  let parser: Parser;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MikroORM,
          useClass: MikroORM,
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Entity1),
          useFactory: repositoryMock,
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Entity2),
          useFactory: repositoryMock,
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Entity3),
          useFactory: repositoryMock,
        },
        Parser,
      ],
    }).compile();

    parser = moduleRef.get<Parser>(Parser);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(parser).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Everything works as expected, untill it comes to method decorated with `@UseRequestContext`.

```
@UseRequestContext()
  async upsertEntity(data: Data[], parser: number): Promise<void> {
    try {
      // code
    } catch (e) {
      throw e
    }
  }
```

Parser signature:

```
  constructor(
    private orm: MikroORM,
    @InjectRepository(Entity1) private entity1Repository: Entity1Repository,
    @InjectRepository(Entity2)
    private entity2Repository: Entity2Repository,
    @InjectRepository(Entity3)
    private entity3Repository: Entity3Repository,
  ) {
    super();
  }
```

When jest meets test that calls `upsertEntity`, it fails with error:

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: @UseRequestContext() decorator can only be applied to methods of classes that carry `orm: MikroORM`".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

So as documentation states (https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#auto-mocking), I have installed `@golevelup/ts-jest` in order to consume `createMock` in a following way:

```
const mikroOrmMock = createMock<MikroORM>();
```

and then in providers:

```
{
  provide: MikroORM,
  useValue: mikroOrmMock,
},
```

But it still wont change error message.

The question is, how to unit test these method, so how to properly mock `MikroORM` dependecy, so unit tests wont require database to be instantiated.

It's really hard to find answers regarding `UseRequestContext` and unit testing in the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error is triggered if `this.orm` of that class where you use the decorator is not instance of `MikroORM` class. If you put a mock in there, it is still not an instance of such class.

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/packages/core/src/decorators/UseRequestContext.ts#L11

Note that in general you still need to do `MikroORM.init()` even if you don't want to connect to the database (you can add `connect: false` to the config or use the second `connect` parameter to disable automatic connection). You need the entity discovery to run in order to use entities (e.g. for propagation to work, we need metadata). So I would suggest not to try to mock everything, it is usually a bad practice that only makes your tests more verbose and tightly coupled to the implementation.

Another thing is instead of providing different implementation, you can use partial mocking via `jest.spyOn` and mock only some methods. This way you still have a real instance of the class that will pass the `instanceof` checks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin's answer I was able to set the MikroOrm instance for Unit tests.

In my case, I only needed to **create the instance and inject it into the BullMQ Queue processor so it correctly forked Entity Manager** for the underlying db queries which happened in a completely different Injected service. I agree that for testing the MikroOrm / Database behavior real database connection should be used.

### How init without connection looks like (using Postgres driver):

```js
import { MikroORM } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { defineConfig } from '@mikro-orm/postgresql';

const orm = MikroORM.init(
  defineConfig({
    connect: false,
    clientUrl: "test",
    schema: "test",
    entities: entities
  })
);
```

### Example in NestJS Unit test

```js
const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [
    JobProcessor,
    {
      provide: Handler,
      useValue: {
        call: jest.fn()
      }
    },
    {
      provide: MikroORM,
      useValue: MikroORM.init(
        defineConfig({
          connect: false,
          clientUrl: "test",
          schema: "test",
          entities: entities
        })
      )
    }
  ]
}).compile();
```

### Example of how ORM was used in the processor

The main reason for the injection of the orm param is the usage of `UseRequestContext` decorator.

```js
@Processor(QUEUE_NAME)
export class JobProcessor extends WorkerHost {
  constructor(
    private readonly handler: Handler,
    private readonly orm: MikroORM, // needed for Context creation
  ) {
    super();
  }

  @AddTrace({
    operationName: 'processor.handleGroupImmediate',
  })
  @UseRequestContext()
  async process(
    job: Job<JobDto, undefined, typeof QUEUE_NAME>,
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      await this.handler.exec(job.data);
    } catch (e) {
      logger.error(e, {
        message: 'Processor failed',
        job,
      });
      if (e instanceof ResponseValidationException) {
        const unrecoverable = new UnrecoverableError(
          'ResponseValidationException',
        );
        unrecoverable.cause = e;
        throw unrecoverable;
      }
      throw e;
    }
  }

  @OnWorkerEvent('failed')
  onWorkerFailed(job: Job<unknown>, error: Error): void {
    logger.error(error, {
      message: 'onWorkerFailed',
      job,
    });
  }

  @OnWorkerEvent('error')
  onWorkerError(job: Job<unknown>, error: Error): void {
    logger.error(error, {
      message: 'onWorkerError',
      job,
    });
  }
}
```